# How to render HTML in a partial with ng-bind-html and $sce inside ng-repeat -> ng-switch -> ng-include?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

As mentioned in the title, i can't figure out how to render html inside a partial with ng-bind-html.

Here is a plunker to illustrate.

http://plnkr.co/edit/YFfHsahcum7XA8GcH6b2?p=preview

I tried several combinations of ng-bind, ng-bind-html, $sce.trustAsHtml, {{HTMLString}} but none of it worked. Maybe I'm missing something completely different?

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jocryv?p=preview) for Item A.

I only moved the `ItemCtrl` inside the template for `ng-include`.  I think the main issue was access to the outside scope.

template is now:

```
Item A: 
<div ng-bind-html="trustedContent" ng-controller='ItemCtrl'></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Fix: http://plnkr.co/edit/7qd3INmYAmUfJPluwfem?p=preview

```html
  <div ng-controller='ItemCtrl'>
    <div ng-switch on="item.type">

        <div ng-switch-when="A">
            <div ng-include='"item_A.html"' ></div>
        </div>

        <div ng-switch-when="B">
            <div ng-include='"item_B.html"'></div>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

I have moved the `ItemCtrl` definition outside the `ng-switch` and `ng-include`.
It is not always wise to mix `directives` with ambiguous priorities together: `ng-include` was creating a scope which inherited from the parent scope, but the scope of the `controller` remained separate.

Making the controller's scope the parent scope solved the problem.

Comment: thank you for clarification... i marked Davin's answer as accepted, that way i can bind different controllers by item.type.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.0" data-semver="1.2.0" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-sanitize@*" data-semver="1.1.5" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .ac {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
    .bc {
      background-color: orange;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngSanitize']);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.items = [{
        "type": "A",
        "url": "item_A.html",
        "content": "<div class=\"ac\">content A</div>"
      }, {
        "type": "B",
        "url": "item_B.html",
        "content": "<div class=\"bc\">content B</div>"
      }]
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-switch on="item.type">
      <div ng-switch-when="A">
        <div ng-include="item.url"></div>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="B">
        <div ng-include="item.url"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

item_A.html:

```
Item A: 
<div ng-bind-html="item.content"></div>
```

item_B.html:

```
Item B: 
<div ng-bind-html="item.content"></div>
```

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ldCV6V?p=preview)

Comment: Thats interesting. No need for $sce?!